# Magento - Exception when customer tries to print order 'Invalid method Mage_Page_Block_Html::addAttribute'

Tags: magento

Magento 1.4

When a customer tries to print an order , the error:

```
Invalid method Mage_Page_Block_Html::addAttribute(Array
(
    [0] => meta_description
)
)
```

Is thrown.

And the full stack trace:

```
#0 [internal function]: Varien_Object->__call('addAttribute', Array)
#1 /chroot/home/shopz/shopz.co.uk/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(347): Mage_Page_Block_Html->addAttribute('meta_descriptio...')
#2 /chroot/home/shopz/shopz.co.uk/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(213): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateAction(Array, Array)
#3 /chroot/home/shopz/shopz.co.uk/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#4 /chroot/home/shopz/shopz.co.uk/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /chroot/home/shopz/shopz.co.uk/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(270): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#6 /chroot/home/shopz/shopz.co.uk/html/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/controllers/OrderController.php(237): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout()
#7 /chroot/home/shopz/shopz.co.uk/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Sales_OrderController->printAction('print')
#8 /chroot/home/shopz/shopz.co.uk/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(253): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch()
#9 /chroot/home//shopz/shopz.co.uk/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match('print')
#10 /chroot/home//shopz/shopz.co.uk/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(304): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#11 /chroot/home//shopz/shopz.co.ukhtml/app/Mage.php(596): Mage_Core_Model_App->run()
#12 /chroot/home//shopz/shopz.co.uk/html/index.php(80): Mage::run(Array)
```

Looking through '`/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php`' it seems that the Block is invalid for the sales invoice . Everything seems fine within the template file.

Answer (score 0):

Best is to check in page.xml file if there's any reference to the addAttribute method.
It might look like:

```
<action method="addAttribute" ...
```

Removing the unnecessary call should help.